# Mikehaertl wkhtmltopdf set different options to different pages

Tags: php

I am generating pdf files with wkhtmltopdf and i need to set different options to
different pages.

For example:

```
$pdf->addPage('http://frontbeta/')->setOptions(['orientation' => 'landscape']);
$pdf->addPage('http://backbeta/');
```

So, landscape orientation for the 1 page and portrait orientaion to the 2 page.
But the code above sets the first option to all pages.

Here is the function that that generates pdf files:

```
    protected function createPdf()
{
    if ($this->_isCreated) {
        return false;
    }
    $command = $this->getCommand();
    $fileName = $this->getPdfFilename();

    $command->addArgs($this->_options);

    foreach ($this->_objects as $object) {
        $command->addArgs($object);
    }
    $command->addArg($fileName, null, true);    // Always escape filename
    if (!$command->execute()) {
        $this->_error = $command->getError();
        if (!(file_exists($fileName) && filesize($fileName)!==0 && $this->ignoreWarnings)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $this->_isCreated = true;
    return true;
}
```

Here, it sets the options to foreach objects. So How can i change the function?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), I found `-O landscape`. You can change your command by adding this option.

[image]

Comment: That is true, but only as a global option, for the whole file. AFAIK, there is currently (and sadly) no option in wkhtmltopdf for setting the orientation on a page level.  There are some possibilities with rotating the page with CSS (that I'm trying right now), but that would probably be satisfying only with the simplest scenarios.  There's official feature request on it, here: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1564. See if you can help anyhow.